# Finding emtpy lines and lines with one column in a file

Tags: bash

I have a large two column file where each column is an integer. How can I search for 1) empty lines or 2) lines with one column?

Actually the file is not parsed by the program and there are some broken rows there! Is there any bash fun for this purpose.

UPDATE:

Assume the content of the file looks like

```
1232 65
54 65

656 76
324
```

I want to remove the empty file and remove the row with one column. Even locating (finding the line numbers) of empty and one columned lines are fine.

If I use `grep -F "\n" file`, it returns nothing although I have intentionally inserted a `\n` in a sample file.

Comment: What do you mean by "search for empty lines"? If you search for empty lines, the output will be empty, because the lines you found are empty. Do you perhaps mean filter-out empty lines to only show non-empty ones, **or** return 1 if the file contains any empty lines? It would make it a bit clearer to see a sample of the file itself, with some bad lines, as well as a sample of what output you need to get.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Let's say if the line is '\n`, then remove it.

Comment: `grep -v ^$ file1` or `grep -vE '(^\S+$)' file1` or both together `grep -E '(^\S+\s+\S+)' file1 > file2`

Comment: @Cyrus: I know how to replace `\n` with a character, e.g. space with `sed`. I am looking for removing '\n` in the file.

Comment: @alecxs: All commands, print the content of file! I see many rows with two columns.

Comment: Finally, what do you want to print? Number of empty lines? Number of rows with one column? The rows with one column? The rows with two columns without the empty lines?

Comment: change the `-v` flag to invert (as you like) and redirect output to other file (as in last example) or directly into while read loop `done <<< $(grep)`

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: @alecxs: The last command is useful. It will copy the content to a new file without `\n` or rows with one column. Thank you

Comment: the first two are for 1) empty lines **or** 2) lines with one column (and of course you can redirect > file2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove empty and one column rows

```
awk 'NF>1' file > output
```

To count and locate the line numbers of empty and one column rows:

```
> cat test.awk
NF==0{ em[++i]=NR; next }
NF==1{ on[++j]=NR }
END { 
    print "empty lines:", length(em)
    print "line numbers:"
    for (i=1;i<=length(em);i++) {
        print em[i]
    }
    print "lines with one column:", length(on)
    print "line numbers:"
    for (i=1;i<=length(on);i++) {
        print on[i]
    }
}
```

example with the sample input

```
> cat file
1232 65
54 65

656 76
324

> awk -f test.awk file
empty lines: 1
line numbers:
3
lines with one column: 1
line numbers:
5
```